# Can one use Airport (Time Capsule) with an external DHCP server?

Tags: mac, networking, dhcp, airport, time-capsule

I currently share my DSL connection using a wireless router with DHCP disabled, and dnsmasq running on a Mac Mini serving DHCP & DNS.  This setup is important because I have clients doing PXE boot, and I need the control over DHCP that dnsmasq provides.  There is also a Time Capsule on the network that's used purely as a backup device; its wireless functions are disabled.

The wireless router is starting to get a little flaky, and since it doesn't support 802.11n I'd like to replace it.  Rather than buying a new router, I'd like to just use the Time Capsule.  But I see no way to disable its DHCP server; when I set the connection type to PPPoE, it insists on serving DHCP.

Is there any way to use Airport PPPoE with a DHCP server elsewhere on the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

PPPoE requires NAT, and on AirPort base stations (including Time Capsules), there is no way to enable NAT without DHCP.

Previously some people would set their base station's DHCP settings to a zero-length range so that only their external DHCP server would be capable of serving leases. But with the recent 7.5.2 firmware upgrade, the base station started blocking DHCP offers from external DHCP servers (this sorta makes sense; for most consumers, when they have more than one DHCP server on the network, it means they accidentally left DHCP enabled on more than one device when they didn't mean to or didn't know better).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest f[irmware update 7.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1471) in tangent with the iOS app, you can now setup NAT without DHCP on a Airport/Time Capsule.